# Guardar datos de formularios generados dinámicamente con PHP, jQuery y Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, formularios, objeto

Tengo un formulario donde hay varios campos. Cada uno de los campos es una categoría que es creada desde la aplicación (Es decir, puede haber tanto 1 como 20).

El problema que tengo, es que en el formulario, donde se les puede cambiar el nombre a cualquiera de ellas, no puedo recoger el valor de los campos (Uso jQuery) para enviarlos mediante **Ajax** a un archivo **PHP** **(Ya que NO sé formar una variable de tipo objeto con todos los parámetros)**.

**Ejemplo:**

```
              __________
Deportes:    |__________|   // <input id="deportes"></input>
Videojuegos: |__________|   // <input id="videojuegos"></input>
Música:      |__________|   // <input id="musica"></input>
```

Lo de arriba son los inputs que se muestran de forma dinámica.

Ahora, lo que no consigo hacer es pasar los los valores de todos los inputs a este objeto: (Que es el que se envía con el método POST en el Ajax)

```
var parametros = {};
```

Puede que la forma de hacerlo no tenga sentido dado que esto solo es un ejemplo, no he puesto mi caso real, pero si esto funciona, lo puedo aplicar a mi app.

Comment: Si publicaras el código real sería más fácil. Pero si estás accediendo al formulario de alguna forma, podes hacer un [`$('.form').serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) y pasar eso como parámetros del POST.

Comment: @azeós Sí, la idea es simplemente acceder a campos cuya existencia e ID sean desconocidos. Me sirvió, muchas gracias.

Comment: Dejo mi comentario como respuesta así podes marcar como resuelta la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que querés hacer es enviar todos los `input`s de un formulario por AJAX, lo más simple es usar [`.serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Tené en cuenta que el nombre que se usa para enviar cada input es el `name` del mismo, no el `id`. Aclaro por las dudas porque es a lo que hiciste referencia.

Ejemplo:

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('/envio', data, function (results) {
        // Success
    });
});
```